# Another "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)" narrowed down to QPixmap

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qpixmap

There are plenty of questions around regarding such error code, but I found no specific info for this case.

After debugging and narrowing down the piece of code first throwing the error, I found it boils down to:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QPixmap
>>> a = QPixmap()

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

And at this point I am stuck. According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) it is possible to construct an empty `QPixmap`. Why was I doing this? To track the source of the issue, which I cannot continue as of now. The actual context is that I want to create `QIcon`s for a Ui, but that fails with the mentioned error.

(Windows 10, python 3.8.11, PyQt5 5.15.4, pyqt (conda) 5.9.2, in PyCharm 2021.2.1 CE with conda env)

Comment: `QPixmap`s require a `QApplication` to exist first, like many other types in Qt => add `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])` in between the lines and it should work.

Comment: @Jeronimo if no widget is required, `app = QtGui.QGuiApplication([])` is sufficient.

Comment: @musicamante Yes that kind of answers my question. But only with the explicit statement of Jeronimo I got aware of this. I could not find it in the docs. Could you point me out how to get to a docs source for this? ... All in all these comment answer my problem.

Comment: In various pages of the documentation it's explained that QImage is intended for I/O access, while QPixmap for displaying on screen (which implicitly means that it requires at least QGuiApplication as any other screen related object (like QTextDocument). In any case, the rule of thumb is that if you need something from a module, you probably need the related application in order to properly use it: if it's from QtWidgets, you need a QApplication instance, if it's QtGui, QGuiApplication, and eventually QCoreApplication for basic QtCore objects that need an event loop (like QTimer).